# Selecting algorithms to test their performance on sentiment analysis performance

Tags: nlp, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis

Hello and thank you for your time. I am a budding data analyst and working on my first extensive project which is on NLP and sentiment analysis.

I have made use of Random Forest, Multinominal Naive Bayes, BERT and such models. However, I am trying to implement logistic regression too and came across the codes for it but they don't mention "Multinominal".  When I read online, I can see there exists Multinominal Logistic Regression.

My question is : DO I USE LOGISTIC REGRESSION OR MULTINOMINAL LOGISTIC REGRESSION? WHAT'S THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THEM? THEY TALK ABOUT PROBABILITY BEING BINARY? HOW AND WHAT DO I CHOOSE SINCE SENTIMENT CONTAIN "NEUTRAL" EMOTIONS ALONG WITH "POSITIVE" AND "NEGATIVE" EMOTIONS AND AREN'T BINARY?

Comment: No need to put your final paragraph in all-caps.

Answer (score 0):

You use logistic regression when your problem is binary: true/false, yes/no, buy/sell, positive sentiment vs. negative sentiment.

It actually gives you a probability, and you choose a *threshold*. E.g. >0.5 is positive sentiment, <=0.5 is negative sentiment. Your choice of threshold affects the precision vs. recall of your model (see ROC curves).

When you have multiple categories is when you use multinomial logistic regression. The categories are considered to have no ordering. E.g. is someone's favourite colour red, blue or green. Or is the species of iris A, B or C.

You should also look into *ordinal* logistic regression, which is when you have multiple categories, but they have *an order*. For instance, is the sentiment positive, neutral or negative. Or is my answer very helpful, helpful, not much use or absolutely useless. :-)